# Postgres dynamic partition

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'd like to write a query where my `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` depend on values in an associated table:

If the value of `movements.has_weight: true` for :

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(id) 
OVER 
  (PARTITION BY user_id, movement_id, reps ORDER BY weight DESC)
AS id
FROM logs
INNER JOIN movements
ON logs.movement_id = movements.id
```

If `movements.has_weight: false`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(id) 
OVER 
  -- cf the above, we don't partition over reps, and we order by reps instead of weight
  (PARTITION BY user_id, movement_id ORDER BY reps DESC)
AS id
FROM log
INNER JOIN movements
ON logs.movement_id = movements.id
```

The point of the query is for a weightlifting log:
For each movement list the highest number of reps logged (if there is no weight, e.g. a push up), or if there is weight, list each number of reps along with the highest weight logged (e.g. a bench press).

Can I achieve this in one query?

Comment: `case when movements.has_weight then FIRST_VALUE(id) 
OVER 
  (PARTITION BY user_id, movement_id, reps ORDER BY weight DESC) else FIRST_VALUE(id) 
OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, movement_id ORDER BY reps DESC) end `?..